# Angularjs: Dependency injection. "is not a function" error

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm having my first go at dependency injection. My goal is to eventually just enable some simple communication between two controllers. I'm not even getting far enough to even worry about handling the communication with the second controller. I'm getting an "is not a function error" for ContactMessages.AddNewContact(response.data);

When I use self.ContactMessages.AddNewContact(response.data); I get "Cannot read property 'AddNewContact' of undefined"

I just want to invoke the AddNewContact function of the ContactMessages factory.

This should be a fairly basic procedure.

```
<html ng-app="myApp"><head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var userName = 'some email'; //pseudo code
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('ContactMessages', [function() 
{   var tmpContact = {};

    this.AddNewContact = function(objContact){
        this.tmpContact = objContact;
    };
    return tmpContact;
}]);

app.controller('ActionsController', function ($scope, $http, ContactMessages){
        this.newContact = {
            Email: "",
            Type: "",
            Frequency: "",
            UserName: userName
        };
        var self = this;

        this.AddContact=function()
        {   

            $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'some url', //pseudo code
            data: this.newContact,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
            }).then(function successCallback(response) 
                {   if(angular.isObject(response.data))
                        self.ContactMessages.AddNewContact(response.data);
                }, function errorCallback(response) {

            });
        };
    }); 
</script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ActionsController as ActCtrl">
<div>
    <form name="frmAddContact" noValidate>
        <input placeholder="Contact Email" type="email" ng-model="ActCtrl.newContact.Email" required></input>
        <select ng-model="ActCtrl.newContact.Type"  required>
            <option value="">Contact Type</option>
            <option value="COLLEAGUE">Colleague</option>
            <option value="FRIEND">Friend</option>
            <option value="FAMILY">Family</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-model="ActCtrl.newContact.Frequency"  required>
            <option value="">Contact Frequency</option>
            <option value="ANY">Any Time</option>
            <option value="WEEKLY">Weekly</option>
            <option value="MONTHLY">Monthly</option>
            <option value="QUARTERLY">Quarterly</option>
            <option value="YEARLY">Yearly</option>
        </select>
        <div >
            <button ng-click="ActCtrl.AddContact()" ng-disabled="frmAddContact.$invalid" >Add Contact</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div></body></html>
```

Comment: I've isolated the issue to the inability to call ContactMessages.AddNewContact from inside the $http request. I can call   said function from inside AddContact.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Hi change your Factory like this

```
app.factory('ContactMessages', [
    function () {
        var o = {};

        o.AddNewContact = {};
        return o;
    }
]);
```

for refrence https://plnkr.co/edit/sYSJ5ZOVQUX0ctir2EmM?p=preview

Comment: Made the changes as suggested. This results in the same error messages as before.

Comment: var self = this; u have to move on top not inside the this.AddContact=function()  , before the  this.newContact move your var self = this;